# tikz arrow package define where to put the base (starting point) of an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am having trouble trying to make tikz to locate the arrow based on the base of the arrow and not on the center. It seems that the center is the default. How can I overwrite that default?

Here is a MWE:
\

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[shapes.arrows]
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7, every node/.style={single arrow, draw=none}]
    \begin{axis}[ xmin=-1.0,xmax=1.0,
        ymin=-0.2,ymax=6.7,
      ]
      \plot[name path=A, thick,samples=100,domain=-1:1] {4- sin(180*x)};
      \plot[name path=B,thick,samples=100,domain=-1:1] {1+x^2};
      \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between [of=A and B];
      \draw[dotted] (-1,0)--(-1,2);
      \draw[dotted] (1,0)--(1,2);
      \node [fill=green, single arrow head indent=1ex,minimum height=5cm,
      minimum width=2cm,rotate=90] at (-0.5,1.25) {};
      \node[] at (-0.5,1.25) {Start Here!};
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{I need the arrwo to start in the bottom curve}
  \label{subfig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here the picture:
[image: move arrow up please]

Answer (score 2):

Add `anchor=west` to the node options. You need the `west` anchor, not the `south`, because the node is rotated, and the anchors of the node are rotated along with it.

If your intention is to draw a fat arrow between the two functions though, you're better off using something like

```
  \draw [line width=5mm,
         -{Stealth[width=15mm, length=10mm, inset=1mm]},
         blue]
         (-0.5, {G(-0.5)}) -- (-0.5, {F(-0.5)});
```

I think, where `F` and `G` are functions defined with `declare function`. (You don't have to do that though, you could write the function expressions directly in the coordinates, replacing `x` with `-0.5`.) The `Stealth` arrow tip is from the `arrows.meta` library, so that has to be loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz, you don't have to do it explicitly
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
     every node/.style={single arrow, draw=none},
     declare function={
       F(\x) = 4- sin(180*\x);
       G(\x) = 1+\x*\x;
       }
     ]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1.0,xmax=1.0,
        ymin=-0.2,ymax=6.7,
        width=10cm,
        samples=100,
        domain=-1:1
      ]
      \addplot[name path=A, thick] {F(x)};
      \addplot[name path=B,thick] {G(x)};
      \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between [of=A and B];
      \draw[dotted] (-1,0)--(-1,2);
      \draw[dotted] (1,0)--(1,2);
      \node [fill=green, single arrow head indent=1ex,minimum height=5cm,
      minimum width=2cm,rotate=90, anchor=west] at (-0.5,1.25) {};
      
      \draw [line width=5mm,
             -{Stealth[width=15mm, length=10mm, inset=1mm]},
             blue]
             (-0.5, {G(-0.5)}) -- (-0.5, {F(-0.5)});
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{I need the arrwo to start in the bottom curve}
  \label{subfig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent anwer!. You made my day. Thanks so much.